# Questions on the paper "On the finitistic global dimension conjecture for Artin algebras"

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

I am reading the paper [*On the finitistic global dimension conjecture for Artin algebras*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240152799_On_the_finitistic_global_dimension_conjecture_for_Artin_algebras).
On page two, there are two lemmas:

> **Lemma 0.1 (Fitting’s Lemma)**
>
> a)
>   Let $M$ be a f.g. module over a Noetherian ring $R$ and let $f \colon M \to M$ be an endomorphism of $M$.
>   Then for any submodules $X$ of $M$ there is an integer $n$ so that $f$ sends $f^m(X)$ isomorphically onto $f^{m+1}(X)$ for all $m \geq n$.
>   Let $\eta_f(X)$ denote the smallest such value of $n \geq 0$.
>
> b)
>   If $Y$ is a submodule of $X$ then $\eta_f(Y) \leq \eta_f(X)$.
>
> c)
>   If $R$ is an Artin algebra and $X = M$ there is a direct sum decomposition $X = Y \oplus Z$ so that $Z = \ker f^m$ and $Y = \operatorname{im} f^m$ for all $m \geq \eta_f(X)$.
>
> Let $K_0$ be the abelian group generated by all symbols $[M]$, where $M$ is a f.g. $\Lambda$-module, modulo the relations:
>
> 1. $[C] = [A] + [B]$ if $C \approx A \oplus B$.
> 2. $[P] = 0$ if $P$ is projective.
>
> Then $K_0$ is the free abelian group generated by the isomorphism classes of indecomposable f.g. nonprojective $\Lambda$-modules.
>   For any f.g. $\Lambda$-module $M$ let $L[M] = [\Omega M]$ where $\Omega M$ is the first syzygy of $M$.
>   Since $\Omega$ commutes with direct sums and takes projective modules to zero this given a homomorphism $L \colon K_0 \to K_0$.
>   For every f.g. $\Lambda$-module $M$ let $\langle \operatorname{add} M \rangle$ denote the subgroup of $K_0$ generated by all the indecomposable summands of $M$.
>   Let
>   $$
>   \phi(M) := \eta_L \langle \operatorname{add} M \rangle.
> $$
>
> **Lemma 0.2**
>
> a)
>   If $M$ has finite projective dimension than $\phi(M) = \operatorname{pd} M$.
>
> b)
>   If $M$ is indecomposable with $\operatorname{pd} M = \infty$ then $\phi(M) = 0$.
>
> c)
>   $\phi(A) \leq \phi(A \oplus B)$.
>
> d)
>   $\phi(kM) = \phi(M)$ if $k \geq 1$.
>
> (Original picture of the above text [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvbHG.png).)

I am confused at some places:

1. $K_0$ is the free ablian group, so it can be seen as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Notherian ring. But here how to make sure $K_0$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module to use Lemma 0.1?
2. How to prove a), b) in Lemma 0.2? (I don't know why there are connections between $\phi(M)$ and the projective dimension of $M$.)
3. Does $kM$ in d) mean the direct sum of $k$ many copies of $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not really necessary in 0.1 a) to assume that $M$ is finitely generated, one only needs that $X$ is a finitely generated (hence Noetherian) submodule of $M$. That is clearly the case for $\langle \mathrm{add}\,M\rangle$.
2. To show 0.2 a): 
   For an (indecomposable) direct summand $N \leq_{\oplus} M$, we have $\mathrm{pd}\,N \leq \mathrm{pd}\,M$.
   Consider a finite projective resolution 
   $$0\longrightarrow P_n \stackrel{p_n}\longrightarrow P_{n-1}\stackrel{p_{n-1}}\longrightarrow \dots \longrightarrow P_1 \stackrel{p_1}\longrightarrow P_0 \stackrel{p_0}\longrightarrow N \longrightarrow 0$$
   where $n=\mathrm{pd}\,N.$ Then $\Omega N=\ker p_0, \;\Omega^2 N=\Omega \Omega N=\ker p_1, \dots, \Omega^n M=\ker p_{n-1}=P_n$. Thus, $L^n([N])=[P_n]=0$. Note that all the syzygies $\Omega N, \;\Omega^2 N, \dots \Omega^{n-1} N$ were non-projective, so $L^i([N])\neq 0$ for $i < n$.

On the other hand, if $M=\bigoplus_{j=1}^mN_j,$ then $\mathrm{pd}\,M=\mathrm{pd}\,N_j$ for some $j$: This is because one can sum up the projective resolutions as above to produce a projective resolution of $M$ (whose length is $\max \{\mathrm{pd}\,N_j\;|\; j=1,2, \dots, m\}$). Altogether, since $[N_1], \dots [N_m]$ are the generators of $\langle\mathrm{add} M\rangle$, we see that $$L^k(\langle\mathrm{add} M\rangle)=0,  \; L^{k-1}(\langle\mathrm{add} M\rangle)\neq 0,$$
where $k=\mathrm{pd}\, M$. This shows that $L:L^{k-1}(\langle\mathrm{add} M\rangle) \rightarrow L^{k}(\langle\mathrm{add} M\rangle)$ is not injective, but after that, $L:L^{t}(\langle\mathrm{add} M\rangle) \rightarrow L^{t+1}(\langle\mathrm{add} M\rangle)$ for $t \geq n$ of course injective is, since it is the zero map between zero modules.

As for $b)$: Note that by an argument as above, $L^n$ does not ever vanish on $\langle[M] \rangle$. That means that for any $n,$ the map $L: L^n(\langle [M] \rangle) \rightarrow L^{n+1}(\langle [M] \rangle)$ is a nonzero map between cyclic modules **inside free Abelian group**, i.e. between free Abelian groups of rank one. That automatically means that the map is injective. This means that $\phi(M)=0$.

3. If I had to guess, I would say that it is a slight misuse of notation, meaning $M^k$, which corresponds to the class $k[M]$ inside $K_0$.

Comment: For question $a),b)$, I think we should find a $n$ such that $L: L^n(\langle addM \rangle) \rightarrow L^{n+1}(\langle addM \rangle)$ or $L: L^n(\langle M \rangle) \rightarrow L^{n+1}(\langle M \rangle)$ is an isomorphism. But why you show that $L$ is injective?

Comment: As I wrote, the point that for any $k$, $L^n(\langle [M] \rangle)$ is a cyclic subgroup of the free Abelian group $K_0$ (it is an homomorphic image of the cyclic group $\langle [M] \rangle$). And since $K_0$ is free, $L^n(\langle [M] \rangle)$ cannot be a finite cyclic group ($L^n(\langle [M] \rangle) \neq 0$ since the hom. $L^k$ does not vanish on $[M]$), so it is the infinite cyclic group, i.e. free of rank one. Same goes for $L^{n+1}(\langle [M] \rangle)$, so $L$ is an epimorphism between two rank $1$ free Abelian groups. This can happen only if it is an isomorphism.

Comment: And, of course, all the maps are automatically surjective since the codomain is always chosen as the image. That is, $L^{n+1}(\langle[M]\rangle)=L(L^{n}(\langle[M]\rangle)),$ so the surjectivity is clear a priori and one does need to check only when the map is also injective.